# How to deserialize all json values to strings with Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson

There is a `jackson` feature to write any object fields as strings:

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.enable(JsonGenerator.Feature.WRITE_NUMBERS_AS_STRINGS);
```

How can achieve the opposite? Means: read any json fields as strings, so that any array of `[123, 456]` is read as list of strings `["123", "456"]`?

Comment: This tutorial might help you
https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-map.